# gameObject.name is returning the script name, not the gameobject name

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script, LevelCube, which is attached to a gameobject in my scene. When the object is clicked, it calls a function in this script called PickCube()

Right now, I'm just trying to get the position of this gameobject in my scene.

Here is my function:

```
public void PickCube ()
    {
        Debug.Log (gameObject.name);
    }
```

Curiously, the output of this log just says "LevelCube", the name of the script. I thought gameObject referenced the GameObject the script is attached to. What's going on here?

If it's any use, here is a pick of the editor. You can see InvertedSphere is highlighted. This is the gameobject I'm trying to get the position of.
[image]

Comment: you're right, it should show the name of the gameobject the script is attached to

Comment: Just tested it, it works as intended in 5.6.1, maybe you should update?

Comment: Works as expected for me on every version of Unity I've ever worked with. Are you absolutely sure that the script that's having its method invoked *is* that sphere? Make the object move when you call `PickCube()` too, or change color, or something.

Comment: @Draco18s You were right! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Draco18 I realized I was supplying a different object which also has the LevelCube script to the onclick method in my event trigger. So it was calling my function for that object rather than my InvertedSphere.

Answer (score -1):

Try `gameObject.transform.name`.
What you see in hierarchy is the name of the transform. If you use `gameObject.name`, it casts it to `Object.name` and you get the name of your current object.

Comment: *`If you use gameObject.name, it casts it to Object.name`* Uh, so does [`transform.name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html), "Components share the same name with the game object and all attached components."